# How can I connect to remote mysql server after removing local mysql server cartridge?

Tags: php, mysql, database, openshift

I have an openatrium site on openshift. I would like to use remote database. That is, not using local database in the same gear anymore. After I removed local mysql server cartridge, I cannot connect to remote mysql server. I got the following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /var/lib/openshift/.../app-root/runtime/repo/php/includes/lock.inc).

My issue is drupal. How to change local mysql to remove mysql for old installation (not building a new site). Anyone can help me to solve this? Thanks.

More further info and tests:

1. The **remote database can be connect from the local gear (openatrium site)**, because I
   wrote php testing code and was able to connect to the databasefrom
   the gear to the remote database.
2. I tried to add **OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_... env variables** (to remote database) so that **Pressflow 7 Settings Helper cartridge** would update database info after git push. It did update the database info in the env variable of Pressflow 7 settings. But still has the same error
3. Use rhc port-forward command, I can connect remote database in my PC through the port from the local gear (drupal site)

PS. I also tried removed **Pressflow 7 Settings Helper** cartridge (https://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=smerrill/openshift-community-pressflow7). And setup the database server settings in drupal manually. The error is the same.

PS. The remote database idea is based on https://blog.openshift.com/sharing-database-across-applications/.

Comment: Have you tried a basic connectivity test to see if the application host can connect to the remote database server? You can do that by trying to connect to the remote server on port 3600 using `telnet`.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, I wrote php code to test and was able to connect to remote database server from local gear. But Drupal cannot.

Comment: I also tried to add OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_ env variables (to remote database) so that Pressflow 7 Settings Helper cartridge would update database info after git push. It did update the database in the env variable of Pressflow 7 settings. However I got the same message.

Comment: I improved/updated the question information above.